# JQuery .load() Issue

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to get the following .load() method to work. The current code does not display the requested page within the div as I would think it should. Thoughts? Also what is the best way to test the .load() method and find out if it is working?

ParentPage.cfm

```
<script>
$("#go_val").click(function() {
  $('#test_div').load('htdocs/mysite/index.cfm?event=test #container');
}
</script>
<form name="parent_form" id="parent_form">
<input type="text" name="myText" id="my_Text" value="TestValue">
<input type="button" name="go" id="go_val" value="GO">
</form>
<div id="test_div"></div>
```

test.cfm (aka index.cfm?event=test)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">Yippee</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks ahead of time. All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you need "htdocs/mysite/" in there?

Comment: Ive tried both ways, with and without the entire directory. The files are in the same folder. Didn't make a difference though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set it on load.

```
$(function(){
$("#go_val").click(function() {
  $('#test_div').load('htdocs/mysite/index.cfm?event=test #container');
}
});
```

Also best way to test is to use http://getfirebug.com/ and view the console to see if the request is being made.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still doesn't update the contents of the div. Here's my code `$(function(){ 
 $("#go_val").click(function() {   
  $('#test_div').load('/htdocs/mysite/pages/jquery_inner_test.cfm #container'); 
 }) 
});`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the click function is registered after the document is ready, since it doesn't exist when you declare it.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(){
    $("#go_val").click(function() {
      $('#test_div').load('htdocs/mysite/index.cfm?event=test #container');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but nothing is still being loaded into the div. Here's the code I tried... $(document).ready(function() { $("#go_val").click(function() { $('#test_div').load('/htdocs/mysite/pages/jquery_inner_test.cfm'); }); });

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'htdocs/mysite/index.cfm?event=test',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(htmldata){
        $('#test_div').html($(htmldata).find('#container').html());
    },
    error: function(a,b,c) {
        alert('Something went wrong: ' + b);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as well, but nothing being loaded into the div. Here's my version of the code:  `$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#go_val").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: '/htdocs/mysite/pages/jquery_inner_test.cfm',
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(htmldata){
    $('#test_div').html($(htmldata).find('#container').html());
   },
   error: function(a,b,c) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + b);
   }
  });
 });
});`

Comment: @user891859 Post it on jsfiddle or something, thats just a mess

Answer (score 0):

When I duplicated your code I saw an error in the firebug console so Adam had the correct way to debug the problem.

*

> missing ) after argument list

*

I changed the function to :

```
$("#go_val").click(function() {
   $('#test_div').load('index.cfm?event=test #container');
})
```

Note the ending parenthesis and that you only need to have the reference to index.cfm (no path) since it is in the same directory as the parent page.

I have done this so many times and firebug is the only way I have made it through to the other side. Best of Luck.